# Python C-API PyUnicode_FromString

Tags: python, python-c-extension

I'm working with the Python C API, and while I've googled and found somewhat cryptic answers (that don't solve my problem), I can't seem to get past this error.

When compiling my program with `gcc -shared [...] 'pkg-config --cflags --libs python3' -fPIC [...]` *(And, yes, the pkg-config line is in backticks)*, but it produces this error message:

```
‘PyUnicodeUCS2_FromString((const char *)"[...]")’ is not a function
```

The line of offending code is simple:
    PyObject *value = PyUnicode_FromString("foo")
which is practically taken from the [Python3 documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/extending/newtypes.html#adding-data-and-methods-to-the-basic-example%28).  *The contents of the example compile fine and run in the Python interpreter without incident with the exact same command line arguments to `gcc`.*

Any help is *greatly* appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Missing ";" somewhere? Also, code says "foo" and the error says "[...]"?

Comment: It's just because I edited out the string contents because they're really long and I guess I changed them differently in the error and the code.

Answer (score 1):

When embedding Python within an development environment (LabVIEW) I have encountered this. I was unable to find the `PyUnicode_FromString` function, from the Python documentation example, but I was able to use `PyUnicodeUCS2_FromString`, in the same way successfully.